# TestFlight not working as usual

Tags: ios, testflight, submission

On `iTunes Connect`, when submitting a build for `External Testing` with `TestFlight`, I fill up the various fields and then click the `Next` button but nothing happens and I do not see any error or warning message. Is there something new, that I might be missing?

Comment: Make sure you're using Safari browser. Apple doesn't always support other browsers perfectly.

Comment: Same here. Tried with everything, even Firefox. No dice. Testflight is broken again.

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot.
I am now in: Waiting for Beta App Review.
One needs to use Safari for this task.

Comment: don't convert tool/brand names into code snippets when asking questions- those entities aren't code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using Safari, or Chrome (Chrome works for me) and that you don't have any blockers enabled.